# How can I return results less than current date?

Tags: mysql

I want to return results from my table that have a date less than today's date. Here is my statement:

```
$today = date('Y-m-d');
SELECT * FROM events WHERE STR_TO_DATE('$today', '%Y-%m-%d') > wp_eventscalendar_main.eventStartDate
```

I can select events in the future without a problem but when I try to select events in the past I don't get any results. My column 'eventStartDate' is set as a Date. Is there some kind of special operator I should be using for this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You probably need:

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE CURDATE() > wp_eventscalendar_main.eventStartDate
```

MySQL tries to compare a String to a Date, which won't work reliably.

Answer (score 2):

You can Use
`select from table_name where date < curdate()`